# Launch Flask app factory (with create_app()) from external file

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-import

Following this [tutorial](https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-flask-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/) to dockerize a Flask stack, I am trying to lauch an existing application from an external *manage.py* file

My app structure goes like:

```
└── services
    └── web
        ├── manage.py
        └── myapp
            └── requirements.txt
            └── myserver
                └──__init__.py
                └──config
                   └──config.py
```

The manage.py file:

```
import os
os.chdir('myapp')
from flask.cli import FlaskGroup
from myapp.myserver import create_app

app = create_app()

cli = FlaskGroup(app)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

and finally, the `myapp/myserver/__init__.py` file (simplified):

```
from myserver.config.config import Config # this file exists and imports work when i launch from pycharm 

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    ...other stuff here
    return app
```

So when I try to run: `python3 manage.py run`, the ouput goes:

```
  File "manage.py", line 4, in <module>
    from myapp.myserver import create_app
  File "/var/www/html/flask-docker/services/web/myapp/myserver/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from myserver.config.config import Config
```

The config import from `__init__.py` cannot be resolved. I tried to solve this with the *chdir* visible in manage.py.

My env variables are the one I got from a working Pycharm flask setup :

```
FLASK_APP="myserver:create_app()"
```

I managed to sucessfully pass the import instruction by replacing :

```
from myserver.config.config import Config
```

by

```
from .config.config import Config
```

but the whole project contains imports beginning by *from myserver*

So the final question is: why the init file inside myserver does not recognize myserver folder/module ? This setup works just fine when I laucnh it via PyCharm

Comment: I don't know if I follow your question completely, but a thing to remember with relative imports, like you have, is that the path changes depending on your working directory. So the imports that work in one directory, won't work in another. So be sure to import relative to whichever directory docker is running form.

Comment: @BrandonKauffman won't `os.chdir` help with this ?

Comment: No actually. I wish I had a good answer for why, but I j can just the code doesn't work that way with the interpreter.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23619595/pythons-os-chdir-function-isnt-working

Comment: I already posted my answer quoting this exact same post. thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brandons comment and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50279818/5677252) led me to a solution

**manage.py**

```
import sys
#this is the fix
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'myapp'))
from flask.cli import FlaskGroup
from myapp.myserver import create_app

app = create_app()

cli = FlaskGroup(app)
## Heading ##
if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

Instead of changing the working directory with `os.chdir`, I change it using `sys.path`. I am now able to use my servers init file

Answer (score 0):

It can't find the module because it doesn't know what directory to search to find the file manage.py.

try to add manage.py information to init file.
from web import manage

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this. Should I import manage.py in the init file ? like this :
`from ...manage import *`

Comment: Yes. You can try doing that

Comment: I tried, that did not change anything unfortunately